# IcmpSendEcho proper size of reply without magic number

Tags: c++, visual-studio, network-programming

I'm trying to use the IcmpSendEcho function and get a mild warning notification (Visual Studio 2019, C++, Win10) about my ReplySize being inadequate.  I've since fixed the code to avoid the warning but only by using a magic number.  My original code snippet was:

```
ReplySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(SendData);
...
dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho(hIcmpFile, ipaddr, SendData, sizeof(SendData), 
    NULL, ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, 5000);
```

To get past the warning, I had to increase the ReplySize by 8, to account for "... buffer should also be large enough to also hold 8 more bytes of data (the size of an ICMP error message)." [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho) So now I have this line:

```
ReplySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(SendData) + 8;
```

I've tried to find an appropriate sizeof(blah), or other macro, to avoid the magic 8 ball, but haven't found the "correct" answer.

Any thoughts on the proper way to get rid of the +8 ?

BTW, my code will compile without warning, but I end up with a nasty green squiggle under the IcmpSendEcho line, wanding over which reveals a popup warning message.  Now that I write this, maybe if I increased my -W level it might output the warning in the more usual fashion.

[image: screen grab of warning]

Comment: There is no pre-defined constant in the API for the `+8`.  Just define your own constant and document it. If you want to understand why it is 8, see [ICMP Error messages and format explained](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/networking-tutorials/icmp-error-messages-and-format-explained.html)

Comment: Hi, have you got an updates?

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-defined constant in the API for the `+8`.  Just define your own constant (and document it as needed), eg:

```
static const DWORD ICMP_ERROR_SIZE = 8;
...
ReplySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(SendData) + ICMP_ERROR_SIZE;
```

If you want to understand why it is 8, see [ICMP Error messages and format explained](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/networking-tutorials/icmp-error-messages-and-format-explained.html)